# AJAX success result according to PHP if statement

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have login form with submit button which calls Javascript function, in that function I call PHP file with AJAX. On PHP side I check if username, email and password are correct and then I return results to div with class Result. I need to return PHP check result and make further actions in javascript, my code:

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['username_or_email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $username_or_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username_or_email']);
    $password_post = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

    $sql = "SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".$username_or_email."' OR `email` = '".$username_or_email."' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    /* Check if username or email exists */
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo "valid_user";
    } else {
        echo "invalid_user";
    }
    /* Check if password is correct */
    if (password_verify($password_post, $row['password'])) {
        echo 'valid_pass';
    } else {
        echo 'invalid_pass';
    }
    $conn->close();
}
```

JQUERY:

```
success: function (data) {
        if (data == "invalid_user") {
            $(".result").fadeIn(500).html("Incorrect username or email.");
        }
        if (data == "invalid_pass") {
            $(".result").fadeIn(500).html("Incorrect password.");
        }
        if (data == "valid_pass") {
           $(".result").fadeIn(500).html("Success, redirecting to account.");

           setTimeout(function() {
              document.location.href = 'nextpage.php';
           }, 2500);
        }
     }
```

So my questionis: how to make check on JQUERY side properly if I have several IF statements on PHP side. After user press login button I want to show that username or pass is correct/incorrect and which one is correct/incorrect, it is needed just for information purpose.

Comment: If you want to send different strings back, you should switch to a json reponse. Just build an array with the information you want to send back and encode and echo that at the end of the php script. Easy to parse in javascript / jQuery as well.

Comment: `and which one is correct/incorrect, it is needed just for information purpose.` - [I strongly advise you to show the same error message for incorrect username and incorrect password!](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13516/how-to-tell-the-user-his-login-credentials-are-incorrect)

Comment: And if this is a requirement that comes from your boss (or higher), tell them that they have got it all wrong and show them the link i posted above. Stand your ground on this! It is your responsibility that [the code you write is ethical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_ethics)

Comment: Cashbee - probably you are right, due to security reasons it might be better not to show what is exactly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to create an array of elements in your PHP file and store all the information you need. For example:

```
$info=array("user"=>"valid","password"=>"invalid");
```

Then, convert the array into a JSON string and simply echo it:

```
echo json_encode($info);
```

Once the data is retrieved, you can easily manipulate them by converting them into a javascript array of elements like this:

```
info=JSON.parse(data);
```

**NOTE:** PHP can only "communicate" with Javascript via **Strings**. JSON Strings is the most commonly used way of achieving such results, due to it's simplicity.